# Why am I getting a Segmentation Fault? When all functions stay in main, it works

Tags: c

When I keep the code in the functions in main, the code works, but when transferring char* to other functions outside of main I receive segmentation fault. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void printArr(char *arr, int count) {

int x;
//print the sorted array:
for(x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    printf("%s\n",arr[x]);
}
}

void sortArr(char *arr, int count) {

// sort the array in descending alphabetical order
int x, y;
char* temp = "";
for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    for (y = x + 1; y < count; y++) {
        if (strcmp(arr[x],arr[y]) <= 0) {
                temp = arr[x];
                arr[x] = arr[y];
                arr[y] = temp;
            }
        }
}

printArr(arr, count);

}
```

Functions like this one do not allow char * to be carried over?

```
void tokenizeArr(char *string, char *arr, char *rest , int count) {

// tokenize the string
char* tok;

tok = strtok(string, rest);

int y = 0;

while (tok != NULL) {
        arr[y] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, rest);
        y++;
}

sortArr(arr, count);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// if there are not 2 arguments, return 0
if (argc != 2) 
    return 0;

/* if string is NULL return 0 */
if (argv[1] == NULL)
    return 0;

/* loop through argv[1] to count how many words are in string */
int x;
int count = 0;


for(x = 0;x < strlen(argv[1]); x++) {

    if (x == 0) {
        if (!isalpha(argv[1][x])) {
            // leave alone
        }
    }

    // add count for word if string ends with a letter
    else if(x == strlen(argv[1])-1 && isalpha(argv[1][x])) {    
        count++;
        continue;
    }

    // add count for word if restricted character comes up and a letter is before it
    else if(!isalpha(argv[1][x]) && isalpha(argv[1][x-1])) {
        count++;
    }
}

// create character pointer to string
char* string = argv[1];

// create an array the size of count
char* arr[count];

//create restrictions:
char rest[] = " \t\n\r\v\f1234567890,.?!@#$%^&*()-_=+]}[{;:<>/~`'";

tokenizeArr(string, arr, rest, count);

return 0;
}
```

What can I change in the code to allow smooth transition from function to function?

Error Diagnostics:
pointersorter.c: In function \u2018sortArr\u2019:
pointersorter.c:22:4: warning: passing argument 1 of \u2018strlen\u2019 makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

if (strcmp(arr[x],arr[y]) <= 0) {
    ^
In file included from pointersorter.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:395:15: note: expected \u2018const char *\u2019 but argument is of type \u2018char\u2019
 extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
               ^

pointersorter.c:22:4: warning: passing argument 1 of \u2018strlen\u2019 makes

pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    if (strcmp(arr[x],arr[y]) <= 0) {
    ^

In file included from pointersorter.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:395:15: note: expected \u2018const char *\u2019 but argument is of type \u2018char\u2019
 extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
               ^

pointersorter.c:22:4: warning: passing argument 1 of \u2018__builtin_strcmp\u2019 makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    if (strcmp(arr[x],arr[y]) <= 0) {
    ^

pointersorter.c:22:4: note: expected \u2018const char *\u2019 but argument is of type \u2018char\u2019

pointersorter.c:22:4: warning: passing argument 2 of \u2018__builtin_strcmp\u2019 makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

pointersorter.c:22:4: note: expected \u2018const char *\u2019 but argument is of type \u2018char\u2019

pointersorter.c:22:4: warning: passing argument 1 of \u2018strlen\u2019 makes

pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from pointersorter.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:395:15: note: expected \u2018const char *\u2019 but argument is of type \u2018char\u2019
 extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
               ^

Comment: How do you expect us to know what's wrong with your code if you don't show it to us?  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Didn't you get **any diagnostics** from your compiler? I get 10 warnings. You must copy the compiler diagnostics into the question itself, and also provide the *mcve* as one piece of code with the includes that you have.

Comment: I added the includes on top, when I compile I get a bunch of warnings for incorrect casting. But when I leave everything in main it works fine!

Comment: And the compiler diagnostics? Please add them to the question. They're very relevant, most probably your argument definitions are incorrect.

Comment: I added some of the diagnostics below, it would not let me add an image

Comment: All the warnings you get are rather errors. Fix them. You also need to make clear what works and what does not work. Read this: [mcve] and this [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `char**`for an array of strings and you try to use `char*` for it.
(Because `char*` is a string)

Comment: @DanielTolentino when main returns your program ends, when you call another function it pops a return address on the stack which i assume youre over writing.  I havent looked at your source though, just read the answer to see if it wasnt accepted.